# AtCoder ABC128Eの回答が何故かRuntimeErrorになります

Tags: c++

[AtCoderBeginnerContest128](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc128)のE問題を
C++14で解こうとしているのですが
RuntimeErrorになってしまいます。
原因をご教授いただければ幸いです。
以下が当該プログラムです。

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define rep(i,n) for(int (i)=0;(i)<(n);(i)++)

int main(){

//設定
 int N,Q,i,j;
 typedef pair<int, int> P;
 cin >> N >> Q;

 vector<int> X(N),S(N),T(N),D(Q);
 set<pair<int, int>> shugo;

 rep(i,N){
  cin >> S[i] >> T[i] >> X[i];
}
 rep(i,Q){
  cin >> D[i];
 }
 rep(i,Q){
  shugo.insert(P(D[i],i));
}

//tieに代入して地点X[i]でソート
 vector<tuple<int, int, int>> a(N);
rep(i,N){
a[i] = tie(X[i], S[i], T[i]);
}
sort(a.begin(), a.end());

//答えを求める
vector<int> ans;
rep(i,Q){
ans[i]=-1;
}
rep(i,N){
 int x,l,r;
 tie(x,l,r)=a[i];
 auto it = shugo.lower_bound(P(l-x,-1));
 while(it!=shugo.end()){
  if((it->first) >= r-x){ break; }
  ans[it->second] = x;
  shugo.erase(it++);
}
}

//表示する
rep(i,Q){
 cout << ans[i] << endl;
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ans`の長さが0なのに`Q`個分添え字でアクセスしてしまっていますね。

```
rep(i,Q){
  ans.push_back(-1);
}
```

とすると、サンプルは通るようになります。(もちろん`ans`のサイズを指定して初期化してもよいでしょう。)

Comment: 出来ました。ありがとうございました。